# ArcMap 10.1 convert layer to CAD - clipping only desired area to send out to DWG

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, convert, autocad

Is there a way to covert a layer to DWG such that only the desired area of the layer is exported out to a DWG?  My issue is that the layer (parcels) contains all parcels for an entire county, so it is a huge amount of information to convert to DWG.  The conversion seems to just freeze up and will not complete.  I actually only need a small area (a few parcels) that I'd like to have in DWG format.  Is there a way to clip or outline a specific area for export to DWG?

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Rob

Comment: Use clip analysis with export to CAD (using model builder) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00100000002p000000

Answer (score 2):

Yes, select the parcels you want to convert using the selection tool, and then use the [Export to CAD](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000001n000000) tool.  It will only create a DWG with those selected features.  If you actually have a layer you want to clip against then you can follow Mapperz suggestion.

[Right click on the layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001000000076000000) in the table of contents...
Data...
Export to cad
Or use the toolbox they both honor the selected features.

Comment: Thanks Brad and Mapperz for your assistance.  It's nice to know that I can either use clip analysis or actually select features for export to CAD.  I really appreciate the help.